# Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured. With SQL Server

Tags: spring-boot

I wonder how I get this error when trying to execute a springboot application. It looks working on my local machine, but when I try to move to a UAT server it returns this error. I have updated the user and password that should work on UAT machine. I have no clue whether it comes from an invalid url or other wrong settings.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Application.propertites:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1434;databaseName=stock;integratedSecurity=true;
spring.datasource.username=CORP\01703057
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
```

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You are defining properties in the `application.properties` and then disable the auto configration for the datasource. What would you expect to happen in this case?

Comment: But even I remove that, it still gives me the same error message.

Comment: remove @EnableAutoConfiguration and rebuild your project. SpringBootApplication already contains EnableAutoConfiguration and including that may result in strange exceptions.

Comment: I have removed that but it still gives me the same error message